# UITableView inside UICollectionViewCell, all UITableViewCells are highlighted when tapping the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making a `UICollectionView` where some of the `UICollectionViewCells` contain a `UITableView`.

This works great, and everything is fine until I tap the `UICollectionViewCell` somewhere else than the `UITableView`. This causes the `setHighlighted` method to be called on all `UITableViewCells` in the table.

Below is a rough scetch of the `UICollectionViewCell`. The `UITableView` only spans from
"cell one" to "cell three". Tapping anywhere outside this table, but inside the `UICollectionViewCell` causes the cells to be highlighted.

```
-------------------------
| Title goes here       |
|                       |
-------------------------
|                       |
|   Cell one            |
-------------------------
|                       |
|   Cell two            |
-------------------------
|                       |
|   Cell three          |
-------------------------
| Button outside table  |
|-----------------------|
```

The call stack looks something like this.

```
[MyTableViewCell setHighlighted:]
[UICellHighlightingSupport highlightView:]
UIApplicationMain
main
```

It seems like the `UICollectionViewCell` forwards a highlight command to all the cells.

I worked around the issue by overloading the `setHighlighted` method in my `UITableViewCell` subclass and not calling the super implementation. This seems a bit hacky though, and I wonder if this behavior can be avoided somehow.

**EDIT:** 
I assume this behavior comes from when the `UICollectionCellView` calls setHighlighted on all its children. Which I understand is useful in most other cases.

Comment: Try to subclass your UITableView and add empty setHighlighted: method for it.

Comment: "I worked around the issue by overloading the setHighlighted method in my UITableViewCell subclass and not calling the super implementation. This seems a bit hacky though, and I wonder if this behavior can be avoided somehow."

Comment: Did you check my answer? What's the problem with just telling the collection view to not highlight the tableview?

Comment: Your answer is correct, and working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried implementing the following `UICollectionViewDelegate`'s method?

```
collectionView:shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:
```

If you return NO for your `UITableView` views in the collection view, then you should be good to go.

Comment: Works like a charm. Didn't think of this one. Cheers!

Comment: Note that in iOS 7.1, returning NO from `collectionView:shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:` actually prevents the cell from being selected. I filed a radar. Open Radar mirror: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5803034198147072

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, and to allow the table view cells to be highlighted when directly tapped, and to avoid overriding collectionView:shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath: since it prevents selection from happening, I overrode UICollectionViewCell's setHighlighted method and reversed the highlighting that it did on my table view cells. This way, my table view cells don't appear highlighted when the collection view is selected.

```
- (void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    if (highlighted)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            for (UITableViewCell* cell in self.tableView.visibleCells)
                cell.highlighted = NO;
        });
    }
}
```

I dispatched the highlighting because it appears that UICollectionViewCell delays its highlighting as well. I need my highlighting to happen after UICollectionViewCell's.